# When I print the id it doesn't match the id in "inspect element"

Tags: python, selenium, element

I have a webpage with the following:

```
<span class="plugin_pagetree_children_span plugin_pagetree_current" id="childrenspan173273808-0"> <a href="/display/Cardians/Shift+Turnover?src=contextnavpagetreemode">Shift Turnover</a> </span>
```

and I can successfully find it by link text using `st = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Shift Turnover')`

but when I print the id using `print('-',st.id)`

The id prints out as `63cd644e-495b-4985-8f9e-7ea067a2b6f1` instead of `childrenspan173273808-0`.

I've also attempted to `get_attribute` and `get_property` but those aren't working either.  Any hints/tips/suggestions welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I'm seeing here is that you are trying to get the ID `childrenspan173273808-0`, but your selector `driver.find_element_by_link_text('Shift Turnover')` is locating the `a` element, which has no ID. That is why `get_attribute` is not working for you. You *actually* want to find the `span` element, which contains your desired ID.

You can use this to get the ID `childrenspan173273808-0`:

```
st = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[a[text()='Shift Turnover']]") # locate the span
id = st.get_attribute("id") # get its ID and print
print(id)
```

This XPath locates the `span` element that appears outside of the `a` element with text `Shift Turnover`. We query on the `span` which contains `a` element with `Shift Turnover` text, then call `get_attribute` on the `span` element, to retrieve your desired `childrenspan173273808-0` ID.

Lastly -- the ID `63cd644e-495b-4985-8f9e-7ea067a2b6f1` that was printing out in your example was **not** the `WebElement` ID attribute, but rather, "[the server-assigned opaque ID for the underlying DOM element](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebElement.html)". This is detailed in the Selenium docs on `WebElement`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to retrieve value of web element. You need to use get_attribute method which is declared inside the Web element interface. Basically this method will return the value of the specified attribute in the string format.

**Solution 1:**

```
locator= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='childrenspan173273808']//a").get_attribute("id")
print(locator)
```

**Solution 2:**

```
locator=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='plugin_pagetree_children_span plugin_pagetree_current']//a[1]").get_attribute("id")
print(locator)
```